# Python: If <string> in <string> test always returns false

Tags: python

Here is the test I am running:

```
accget = StringVar()
E2 = Entry(pm, bd =1, textvariable = accget).grid(row=1, column=1)
B2 = Tkinter.Button(pm, text ="Access saved passwords", 
                        command = accesspass).grid(row=1,column=3)


def accesspass():
    for line in reversed(open("passfile.txt", "r").readlines()):
        if str(accget) in line:
            print("yes")   
        else:
            print("no")
```

The set up is in a GUI and when the user fills E2 and presses B2, the programm iterates passfile.txt from the last line up and is meant to print yes if the string is in a line. However, even when a word is in a line or I have placed the whole content of the line in the field, the test always returns false and i get no for everyline.

Can somebody explain why this might be?

Comment: It's hard to tell not knowing the contents of your file. Have tried printing out the lines? Consider using `.strip()` function before comparing strings.

Comment: the file contains a sort of list for matter like line after line of:                   name: corresponding name

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if str(accget) in line:
```

should be

```
if accget.get() in line:
```

Comment: Thankyou! Could you explain why this made a difference?

Comment: accget is a StringVar() and you have to get the value using get()

Answer (score 1):

Two things I would try first.

1. Print variables out, both accget and each line in the file. Make sure you are seeing what you expect.
2. be sure the format of accget is the same as you would expect it to be in line. meaning white space, capitalization, ect.
   Good luck